# How to save to the var, only one from the output

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

Im writing a script that executes dig command on 2 domains, and after next cmd is host on output.
And always i will get for exmaple:

```
findUserServer=for r in $(dig +short $login.example.COM && dig +short $login.example.ORG); do host $r|awk '{print $NF}';done | awk -F "." '{print $1}';

1 output: >> asdf02 example
```

asdf02 - its a server name, its always same name starts "asdf".

Question:  Have you any idea how to save to the variable only asdf02?

question+: asdf02 woudln't be always first, could be example asdf02
Should i do maybe a sed which looks on 4 first characters? If it's "asdf", then: [...]

Comment: you can fold all of the `awk` processing into one awk script AND have it check the data captured to see which one matches `adsdf`. Look at `n=split($NF,".", tmpOutArr);` and then `n++;for(i<n;i++){ if (tmpOutArr[i] ~ /adsf.*/) { print tmpOutArr[i]}}` . Can't take the time now to write up perfectly. This would be a good learning experience for you ;-) . Good luck.

Comment: I thinks I can help, give me the initial input for dig command (of course you need to change your real informations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not to pipe awk commands into each other and so:

```
for r in $(dig +short $login.example.COM && dig +short $login.example.ORG); do host $r;done | awk -F [.\ ] '/asdf02/ { print $10 }'
```

We use both a space and . as delimiters and then pattern match the output for the occurance of asdf02. If we find is, we print the address.

Answer (score 1):

Run that through shellcheck.net ...
Try this.

```
findUserServer="$( for end in COM ORG; do
                    host $( dig +short $login.example.$end );
                   done | sed -n '/ asdf/{ s/^.* //; s/[.].*//; p; }' )"
```

This will run 2 `dig`s and pipe the collective output through `sed`,
which will ignore lines that don't have `asdf`, and strip the matches clean for you.

Let me know if I missed details, because I don't have those exact values available.